# Dynamic change in grouped_collection_select with js.coffee

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need some help in my project. What i am trying to do is to show the subcalltype_field (grouped_collection_select) whenever there is any available for the selected call_field, if not the subcalltype_field should be hidden.

Here is my form.html.erb

```
<h2>New incoming call</h2>
<%= form_for(@call) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.collection_select :calltype_id, Calltype.order(:id), :id, 
                                                :name, :prompt => "Type of call" %>

  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :subcalltype_id, Calltype.order(:id), 
                        :subcalltypes, :name, :id, :subname, include_blank: true %>

  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "What was your call regarding?" %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my call.coffee file

```
jQuery ->
  subcalltypes = $('#call_subcalltype_id').html()
  $('#call_calltype_id').change ->
    calltype = $('#call_calltype_id :selected').text()
    options = $(subcalltypes).filter("optgroup[label='#    {calltype}']").html()
    if options
      $('#call_subcalltype_id').html(options)
    else
      $('#call_subcalltype_id').empty()
```

I am unfamiliar with coffee scripts and jQuery. Am i doing something wrong? Help?

Thanks in advance. Cheers! :)

Comment: If no one provides an answer I'll post the answer for you in jquery and leave it to you to convert to coffeescript.

Comment: thanks! really appreciate it!!